# Import-Module throwing error

Tags: windows, powershell

I just wrote a simple PowerShell script and want to import the `CommunicatorAPI.dll` as mentioned in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243700(v=office.14).aspx). But it's throwing the following error:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'c:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office
>   Communicator\SDK\CommunicatorAPI.dll' was not loaded because no valid
>   module file was found in any module directory.

How can we resolve this?
I tried few things from article fetched from google, but they are not helping.

Comment: 1.Try running PS as administrator. 2. If your OS is x64, then try running x86 version of PowerShell.

Comment: @beatcracker - Yep, I missed that and deleted my comment.

Comment: Have you actually installed the the Communicator SDK and verified that it was installed in that folder?

Comment: You could just seach the HDD for the file and attempt to import the module that way (assuming you don't have other random files named "CommunicatorAPI.dll"): `GCI "C:\Program*" -Include "CommunicatorAPI.dll" -Recurse -EA 4 | Select -First 1 -Expand FullName | IPMO` that'll search both your Program Files folders for the file, and when it finds the first one it expands the full path to it and pipes it to the `Import-Module` alias of `ipmo`